# Swift - Firebase - Authentification email passwordless

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to put an email/passwordless authentification with Firebase (Swift)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth

In the doc, they mention this setup :

```
let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
// The sign-in operation has to always be completed in the app.
actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
actionCodeSettings.setAndroidPackageName("com.example.android",
                                         installIfNotAvailable: false, minimumVersion: "12")
```

I don't understand what is the URL in

```
actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com")
```

What must I put on this URL ?
And the AndroidPackageName is confusing me either. It can be deleted, right ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's on IOS doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/email-link-auth

Comment: In the description right above this snippet, it says `url: The deep link to embed and any additional state to be passed along. The link's domain has to be whitelisted in the Firebase Console list of authorized domains.`

Comment: Yes,but what it is ? What is this URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Auth uses [Firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) (FDL) to pass the email link OTP back to an app. FDL is used for web to mobile redirects. A critical part of the FDL link is the deep link within it (required when constructing an FDL link). If the link is triggered from a device where the target mobile app is installed or a non-mobile device (laptop/desktop, etc), the link is used as a fallback. This link is also useful to pass any additional state back to the landing page. In this case, it will be used as a mechanism to pass the code back to the app or fallback webpage.